# Find the set of interstion of $ \ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ shwoing its elements

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This question is from $\text{p-adic numbers}.$

**My questions are**-

$(1)$ Is the set $  \ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ non-empty?  If non-empty, then what are the elements or the intersection set?

$(2)$ Is the set  $ \ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z}) \cap \mathbb{Q}_p $ non-empty?  If non-empty what are the elements or the intersection set?

I can not conclude the answer.

Please someone help me with details answer or at least hints.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}_3 \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, since $$\frac{1}{2}= \frac{-1}{1-3} = -1-3-9-27- \dots.$$  That (1) is nonempty implies that (2) is.

Similarly, you can prove that any $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_3 \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ so long $3 \nmid b.$

Comment: yes that is one element and so non-empty.. But I need to find the whole and general expression of the intersection set .. Can you do that that  for general $p$?

Comment: Simply inductive construct the inverse power series of $b$ for $\frac{1}{b}.$

Comment: Does  $ \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: Yes. $\mathbb{Q}_p \supset \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Asking someone to put an answer in that special form sounds like you are asking someone to provide the answer to a homework question. That is not a reasonable request.

Comment: @KCd, I  do not mean that. I mean what are the all elements of the intersection set $ (\mathbb{Z}_p \setminus \mathbb{Z} ) \cap \mathbb{Q}_p$ ?